# Loss of information with RankNTypes and do notation

Tags: haskell

Given this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

module MyLib where

import Data.Attoparsec.Text as P

data U = U { c :: forall i. (Integral i) => i }

z :: (Integral i) => Parser i
z = P.decimal

parse :: Parser U
parse = do 
    c <- z
    return $ U { c = c }
```

Why does GHC insist that `c` is of the type of `Integer`, not `forall i. (Integral i) => i`?

```
rankntypesdo.hs:15:22: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘i’ with actual type ‘Integer’
      ‘i’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall i. Integral i => i
        at rankntypesdo.hs:15:14-24
    • In the ‘c’ field of a record
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘U {c = c}’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: return $ U {c = c}
   |
15 |     return $ U { c = c }
   |                      ^
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you're misinterpreting the type signature:

```
z :: (Integral i) => Parser i
```

This does **not** indicate that `z` (or equivalently `decimal`) is a parser that returns a `forall i. (Integral i) => i` (i.e., a value of some general type `i` that's left unspecified at compile time except for its `Integral`-ness).

Rather, it says that `z` is a polymorphic parser function with type of form `Parser i` that can be instantiated for `i` at any specific `Integral` type, so `z` can be a `Parser Int` (parser that returns an `Int`) or a `Parser Word8` (parser that returns a `Word8`) and so on, meaning that if you actually use `z` to parse an integral quantity and it returns a value, that value has a specific, concrete type like `Int` or `Integer` that's known and fixed at compile time.

So, there's no need (and no way, short of converting between numeric types) to store it as a value in "`Integral` type limbo", the way you're trying to do here.

In this specific code, because `c <- z` uses `z` in a context that under-specifies how `Parser i` should be concretely instantiated, GHC applies its defaulting rules to instantiate it at `Parser Integer`.  This gives `c` the type `Integer`, which does not match the type of the field in the `U` constructor, hence the error.

In order to do what you're trying to do, you'd want a parser of type:

```
z :: Parser (forall i. Integral i => i)
```

Because Haskell doesn't support something with the unlikely name of "impredicative polymorphism", this type signature isn't valid.  You can fake it by using a wrapper (exactly the wrapper `U` that you already have), so you *could* write a `z :: Parser U`.  Specifically, you could write it:

```
z :: Parser U
z = do
  n <- P.decimal
  return $ U { c = fromIntegral n }
```

This looks like it's doing something exciting, but it's not.  `P.decimal` is again instantiated at `Parser Integer` by the defaulting rules, so `n` is just an `Integer`, but `fromIntegral` generalizes it to any `Num` type, which satisfies the field type of `U`.  In other words, this is just the "converting between numeric types" I was talking about before.

Comment: I wanted `U` to be like a `newtype` wrapper of `i`, carrying the constraints without loss of information. Can `U` be defined as a function instead? Something like `emulatedDataConstructor :: (Integral i,j) => i -> j -> (i, j)`?

Comment: @sevo Did you want `data U = forall i. Integral i => U i`? The `forall` has to go outside the constructor for that. However a) I smell an XY problem and b) that type probably can and should be algebra'd down to something simpler (`Integer`?) (in the same way that `data U = forall i. Show i => U i` can be reduced to `data U = U String` (pedantically, `Either Natural Int -> String`)). What is `U` *for*?